# Better Performance hget vs get || Using Redis

Tags: java, caching, redis, memcached

Better Performance `hget vs get` || Using **Redis**

1>
`hset key field value`   ---Here `field("dept")` will always be **same(constant)** and key could be **20 char**

```
hset "user1" "dept" 1
hset "user2" "dept" 2
hset "user3" "dept" 2
```

2>

```
set key value   --Here key could be 20 char
set "{user1}dept" 1
set "{user2}dept" 2
set "{user3}dept" 3
```

Q1.
In both cases which `get cmd` will run faster (considering our database has millions of key value pair)

```
hget "user2" "dept"  vs  get "user2" "dept"
```

Q2.  is `hset "user1" "dept" 1`  is equivalent to `{"user1" : {"dept" : 1}}  or {"dept" : {"user1" : 1}}`

Q3. I want to implement expiry on `key and field` which is not possible in case of `hset` is there any alternative?